# Packages not getting installed in python setuptools

Tags: python, python-3.x, build, setuptools

I am packaging a python project which has the following directory structure:

```
toingpkg/
    src/
        subtoingpkg1/
            subsubtoingpkg1/
                ...
                __init__.py
            __init__.py
        subtoingpkg2/
            ...
            subtoingpkg2.py
            __init__.py
        toingpkg.py
        __init__.py
    setup.cfg
    pyproject.toml
```

My setup.cfg is as follows:

```
[metadata]
name = toingpkg
...
classifiers =
    Programming Language :: Python :: 3
...
[options]
package_dir =
    = src
packages = find_namespace:

python_requires = >=3.6
install_requires =
    requests
    pytz

[options.packages.find]
where=src
```

And my pyproject.toml is as follows:

```
[build-system]
requires = [
    "setuptools>=42",
    "wheel"
]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

When I build my package using `python3 -m build` as mentioned in the [docs](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html#package-discovery), I get a whl file in my dist folder but it does not include the files in the root of the `src` directory.

So when I do a `pip3 install dist/toingpackage-xxx-.whl`, the package gets installed (shows up in pip3 list) but I cannot do a:

```
>>> import toingpkg
```

I get:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'toingpkg'

I also tried specifing all the subpackages manually but got the same result. My python environment is 3.8.5, setuptools 45.2.0.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The way it looks `toinpkg` is a module, not a package. You would need to add it to a a `py_modules` list. Look this keyword up `py_modules` to find some hints.